# Как исправить ошибку Array to string conversion?

Tags: php, yii

Всем привет !!! не могу по фиксить ошибку. 
Во view вывожу `echo $form->textField($model->employees, "full_name_ru", array('size' => 60, 'maxlength' => 255));` ->employees это подвязка в модели `'employees' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'RefEmployeesMahala', 'mahala_id','order'=>'position_type ASC')`. Как исправить эту ошибку ? проект на Yii1

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

`textField()` подразумевает, что первым элементом передается модель или ее название, вы же передаете массив связанных моделей (`employees`), что и приводит к провалу в методе [CHtml::modelName](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#modelName-detail). Если вам нужно вывести `textField()` для каждой связанной модели, делайте это в цикле.

Answer (score 1):

Не передавать массив, куда нужно передать строку

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?